# How to use controlled components in Vue to set values in parent component object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I know how to use controlled componenents to emit the value that is selected.  For example,

```
// app-select.vue

<v-select :items="[1,2,3]"  @change="$emit('input', $event)"></v-select>

// parent-component.vue

<app-select v-model="selectedValue" />
```

So changing the value of v-select should change `selectedValue` on the parent component.

But what if I have an object I'd like to have updated by a controlled component with several selectors:

### parent-comp.vue

```
<template>
  <filter-comp> v-model="filterObj"</filter-comp>
</template>
<script>
  import FilterComp from './filtercomp'
  export default {
    components: {
      FilterComp
    },
    data () {
      return {
         filterObj: {}
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

and a child with several inputs capable of emiting on input:

```
<template>
   <v-select :items="filterOneItems" @change="$emit('input', $event)">></v-select>
   <v-select :items="filterTwoItems" @change="$emit('input', $event)">></v-select>
</template>
```

And let's say it would be my goal to make it so that when v-select input is given, it is updated on the parent component like so:

```
filterObj: {
   filterOne: 'value 1',
   filterTwo: 'value 2'
}
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two solutions. First solution, just use prop not two-way binding:

For `parent-comp.vue`

```html
<filter-comp :obj="filterObj"></filter-comp>
```

And for `filter-comp.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-select :items="items" v-model="obj.filterOne"></v-select>
    <v-select :items="items" v-model="obj.filterTwo"></v-select>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
...
  props: {
    obj: {
      type: Object,
      default: {}
    }
  }
...
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbfv1epc/)

Second solution, use `v-model` as you described:

For `filter-comp.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-select :items="items" @change="change('filterOne', $event)"></v-select>
    <v-select :items="items" @change="change('filterTwo', $event)"></v-select>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
...
  methods: {
    change(name, value) {
      this.$emit('input', {
        ...this.value,
        [name]: value
      })
    }
  }
...
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3exo16vh/)